# How to redirect a specific url with subfolder to another url in Windows nginx server?

Tags: nginx, url-rewriting

I am using Windows nginx server and I have the following code in my `nginx.conf` file:

```
location /store {
rewrite ^(.*)$ /?page=myshop redirect;
}
```

However, upon accessing my domain `shop.domain.com/store` then it displays an error message saying `404 Not Found` instead of redirecting to `shop.domain.com/?page=myshop`

Something is broken.
I've been searching for a solution but without success. I need to redirect upon trying to access `shop.domain.com/store/` to `shop.domain.com/?page=myshop`

Maybe I should enable `rewrite module` somewhere in nginx or what may cause this behavior?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

With .htaccess

```
Redirect /store /?page=myshop
```

Alternative: store.php with content:

```
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0; url=shop.domain.com/?page=myshop" />
```